# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'net'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vue.js, webpack, npm

Начал изучать Vue. Пишу график котировок. При подключении api биржи вылазит эта ошибка. Как решить эту проблему?

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'net'
at webpackEmptyContext (eval at ./node_modules/defaultable sync recursive (app.js:3051), <anonymous>:2:10)
at Object.workaround_require (defaultable.js?6987:49)
at require (defaultable.js?6987:77)
at eval (server.js?663d:9)
at defaulter (defaultable.js?6987:83)
at defaultable (defaultable.js?6987:63)
at good (defaultable.js?6987:174)
at Object.eval (server.js?663d:5)
at eval (server.js:242)
at Object../node_modules/hbo-dnsd/server.js (app.js:4014)
```

В интернете вычитал что нужно в файл "webpack.config.js" добавить

`config.node = {
  net: 'empty'
}`

Но у меня нет такого файла. Уже 2 дня насилую гугл

Comment: [в вопрос нужно добавить код при выполнении которого происходит ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь в браузере запустить код, который работает на сервере, который предназначен ТОЛЬКО для работы на сервере. Модуль `net` содержит низкоуровневое АПИ для доступа к TCP сокетам. Очевидно его не будет в браузере.